# Add options to Wordpress backend

Tags: php, wp-admin, html

I hardcoded a page to use for a Wordpress-Site I'm managing but then my boss decided that said page needs to be editable from the backend for our customers.

Long story short:

**How do I add editablity of certain fields as a option in the backend?**

It has to stay persistent even after an update so I'm reluctant to tinker with the wp-admin folder.

**edit02:**
Let me rephrase my question a bit: What do I need in terms of files or which files do I have to edit to get an additional option in my backend that lets me change an image or the contents of a textbox instead of hardcoding it?

Yes, the site has a custom template for that which is why I can't just use the image from the post itself.

**edit03:**
As apparently nobody here know how to code a Wordpress Backend, let me try again.
I want to add options for a certain usergroup to give them the ability to edit my hardcoded pages:
[image: something among those lines]
You know. Let them change the images on the site, leaving their positions intact, changing some text in the header. Basic stuff.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API

Comment: Have you checked [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)?

Comment: I have that plugin installed, so.. yeah. But performance-wise we already use too many plugins. So far I found a way to add said options via implementing a plugin, but that's exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: If the plugin is already installed, you aren't impacting site performance by using it more fully.  ACF seems a great solution for your challenge.  The obvious alternative is using the WP core custom fields which isn't very user-friendly for your content managers.

Comment: Well installed does not equal activated. But I guess if there's no other way this plugin will be mandatory I guess.

Comment: I've played around quite a bit with the "Advanced Custom Fields" and I do not see any way to add options to my backend. I should add that I don't want to add options to the articles but CHANGE CONTENT inside the article by giving a user specific fields.